# Dirac delta in spherical coordinates. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I must show that the integral
$$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int_{\vec{k}}d^{3}k\frac{\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}{\left({\sqrt{|\vec{k}|^2+m^{2}}}\right)^{s}}=\delta^{3}(\vec{x})$$
when $s=0$ by using spherical coordinates. This should be true since $\delta^{3}(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}d^{3}k$

My problem is just the lack of a factor $\frac{1}{2}$ at the final result.

Here is my procedure: (in spherical coordinates)
$$\begin{aligned}
  \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^{3}k\frac{\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})}{\left({\sqrt{|\vec{k}|^2+m^{2}}}\right)^{s}}  
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \sin(\theta) \frac{k^{2}}{(k^2+m^2)^{s/2}}\cos(kx \cos(\theta))\\
    &=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{k^{2}}{(k^2+m^2)^{s/2}}\frac{2\sin(kx)}{kx}dk \\
    &=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{k\sin(kx)}{(k^{2}+m^{2})^{s/2}}dk
\end{aligned}$$
Now, if $s=0$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
    &=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2} x} \int_{0}^{\infty} k\sin(kx)dk \\
    &=\frac{1}{4 \pi^{2} x} \frac{1}{i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  ke^{ikx}dk \\
    &=\frac{1}{2 \pi x} \left(\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  ke^{ikx}dk\right) \\
    &=\frac{1}{2\pi x}\left(-\frac{\partial \delta(x)}{\partial x}\right) \\
    &=\frac{1}{2\pi x^{2}} \delta(x)
\end{aligned}$$
where I used the identity $x\delta'(x)=-\delta(x)$.

This final result is almost the desired one since the Dirac delta in spherical coordinates in this case should be
$$\delta^{3}(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{4 \pi x^{2}}\delta(x)$$
Where is the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ that I'm missing? Greetings and thank you a lot.

Comment: Please note that [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Anyway, are you sure that final answer you're trying to match is right? Does it integrate to 1?

Comment: Yes, it does since angular integral cancels with the 4 pi and the scale factor x^{2} with the same at the denominator. Finally the integral in the radius results 1.

Comment: Even when the delta function is on the boundary of the range of integration...?

Comment: Indeed. Maybe it's helpful to think of the gamma as one of its resolved versions, like a narrow gaussian. Try the calculation and then take the limit.

Comment: I meant delta, not gamma. This is what happens when you comment on here when you're in the middle of another calculation.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score -1):

The general delta function in 3D curved space is
$$
\frac{\delta^{3}({\bf x}-{\bf x}_c)}{\sqrt{ g }}
$$
where $g$ is determinant of metric. For spherical coordinates, you should have $\sqrt{g}=4\pi r^2$, ***if you have spherical symmetry***. Thus you should get
$$
\frac{\delta( r- r_c)}{4\pi r^2}
$$

Edit: Delt function in spherical coordinates. Since $\sqrt{g}=r^2\sin\theta$, the full delta function without any additional symmetries should be
$$
\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}
\delta( r- r_c) \delta( \theta- \theta_c)
\delta( \phi- \phi_c)
$$
if you have axial symmetry, the delta function becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi r^2\sin\theta}
\delta( r- r_c) \delta( \theta- \theta_c)
$$

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question and doesn't address the case where there is a coordinate singularity at $\mathbf x_c$ which is precisely the case here.

Comment: @NiharKarve, kaylimekay, I just want to show that delta function in spherical coordinates is not $\delta(r)/(4\pi r^2)$. $\delta(r)/(4\pi r^2)$ is a delta function in spherical coordinates with an additional symmetry.

Comment: Hello, what is this additional symmetry? and how the function would be if this additional symmetry is not taken into account?

Comment: @Amadeus, sorry for not answering your question directly. See the update.